# Syntax error or access violation CakePHP updateAll

Tags: cakephp, save, syntax-error

Sometimes when I trigger the action "updateAll" from with CakePHP I get a Syntax error or access violation. When I do the following:

```
$variable = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')  <- for instance    
$this->Model->updateAll(
array('my_table_column' => $variable),
array('id' => $id));
```

When I try it the following way I do not get this error:

```
$this->Model->updateAll(
array('my_table_column' => "'".$variable."'"),
array('id' => $id));
```

I was wondering why this happens and if this is a save way to save data etc.

Comment: Its all here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions - updateAll is an atomic operation accepting SQL expressions to be as powerful as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions ) you are supposed to escape those using `Sanitize::escape()`:

```
$this->Model->updateAll(
    array('my_table_column' => "'" . Sanitize::escape($variable) . "'"),
    array('id' => $id));
```

Comment: But I don't understand why to parse variable between [ "'" ] qoutes. At there documentation the don't tell anything about that. Thanks for the Sanitize information, verry usefull.

Comment: To not treat them as SQL expressions. That information is also on that page.

Answer (score 1):

As [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions) says

> The $fields array accepts SQL expressions. Literal values should be quoted manually using DboSource::value(). For example if one of your model methods was calling updateAll() you would do the following:

```
$ds = $this->getDataSource();
$value = $ds->value($value, 'string');
$this->updateAll(
    array('Baker.status' => $value),
    array('Baker.status' => 'old')
);
```

OR if you are doing updateAll in your controller (let's assume you are using Baker model there)

```
$ds = $this->Baker->getDataSource();
$value = $ds->value($value, 'string');
$this->Baker->updateAll(
    array('Baker.status' => $value),
    array('Baker.status' => 'old')
);
```